# How to force a popup to load with the size I want?

Tags: javascript, facebook, popup

I'm using this code

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
 <!--
 function popup_window(url,w,h)
 {
  var width=w;
  var height=h;
  var from_top=350;
  var from_left=500;
  var toolbar='no';
  var location='no';
  var directories='no';
  var status='no';
  var menubar='no';
  var scrollbars='yes';
  var resizable='yes';
  var atts='width='+width+'show,height='+height+',top='+from_top+',screenY=';
  atts+= from_top+',left='+from_left+',screenX='+from_left+',toolbar='+toolbar;
  atts+=',location='+location+',directories='+directories+',status='+status;
  atts+=',menubar='+menubar+',scrollbars='+scrollbars+',resizable='+resizable;
  window.open(url,'win_name',atts);
 }
 </SCRIPT>


<a href="javascript: popup_window('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.google.com/',300,200)">Click to see a demo popup window</a>
```

but after a bit facebook resize the popup to his default size, I need to FORCE the popup to load in the size I want and to stay with that size

Is there any way I can do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to have something:

```
function popup_window(url,w,h)
{
    .......
    var popupWin = window.open(url,'win_name',atts);
    popupWin.onload = function(){
       popupWin.document.height = w;
       popupWin.document.width = h;   
    }
}
```

You need to add that code in popup.

Comment: I made some changes to my answer. Try this

Comment: tryied the new code but still the same, also tryied it without window.open(url,'win_name',atts); but nothing changes :(

Comment: @user1440266 What is your browser and version?

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow to reduce the size. If you try to reduce it manually also, it will just resize itself.

Comment: Ive tested and its work fine to me.

Whats error is showing to you?

Comment: I know that, that's why I'm asking here for any function that can force the popup to a set size

Comment: @Sena it resize itself after 1-2 seconds the popup is loaded, you have to use facebook as url not another site

Comment: 1-2 seconds, that is an assumption that facebook will be loaded and anyways after that also, facebook won't allow to resize. It will change it back to minimum width and height.

Comment: I found that this happens just with popups, if I can open a new istance of the browser (not a new tab or window),just run chrome.exe from javascript like if I clicked on the desktop icon, i should be able to resize the window. Is it possible to do that? I mean to open the browser and to size it in javascript?

Comment: I see that. That is interesting.

Comment: chrome has minimum dimension for pop up. It works in internet explorer.

Comment: tested with internet explorer and nope it resize itself as soon as facebook is loaded, plus it opens two time the popup, I think that if I'm able to run chrome i can try to resize it

Comment: tryied and it resize itself, :( I think it's not possible to force it

Comment: I tried opening google.com instead of the link that you have. Then it is something that is facebook is controlling on that page.

Comment: what if I put something over the popup, like a blank image that hides everything excpets from the share and cancel buttons? remember i can't edit the code of the popup

Comment: I can’t see a convincing reason yet why you would want to do that.